# ¿Porque el Async y Await no me funcionan?

Tags: c#, consola, async-await

Estoy empleando el siguiente codigo

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp4
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            empleando();
        }

        public static async void empleando()
        {
            ObjetoAsync obj = new();
            Task<bool> tarea = obj.metodoasync();
            obj.Saluda();

            bool res = await tarea;
        }
    }

    public class ObjetoAsync
    {
        public async Task<bool> metodoasync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empezando");
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("termiando");
            return true;
        }

        public void Saluda()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hola");
        }
    }
}
```

Pero yo esperaria que en la consola se imprimiera el siguiente orden.

```
empezando
hola
terminando
```

Pero lo que imprime es esto

```
empezando
terminando
hola
```

Alguien sabe porque el await y el task no funcionan?
O talves tengo algun error que no logro ver
si alguien pudiera responder se lo agradeceria de corazon.

Comment: Has probado en hacer  `await obj.metodoasync();` ?

Comment: Creo que el `await` y el `Task` sí funcionan... lo que no funciona es el código que muestras, o la lógica implementada. Hay una gran diferencia.

Answer (score 0):

- La funcion empleando debe regresar Task no void
- En Main debemos esperar a que termine la funcion empleando
- Usar Task.Delay en lugar de Thread.Sleep

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    public class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Task.WaitAll(empleando());
        }

        public static async Task empleando()
        {
            var obj = new ObjetoAsync();
            var tarea = obj.metodoasync();
            obj.Saluda();

            bool res = await tarea;
        }
    }

    public class ObjetoAsync
    {
        public async Task<bool> metodoasync()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("empezando");
            await Task.Delay(5000);
            Console.WriteLine("termiando");
            return true;
        }

        public void Saluda()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hola");
        }
    }
}
```